# Correct way to call SPsite in a spjobDefinition in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010

What is the best way to get the SPSite in the execute method of a Sharepoint JobDefinition?

I am using the next code:

```
SPServer ms = SPServer.Local;
SPSite msite = new SPSite(server);
```

But it does not works when implemented in a Sharepoint Farm ... and if I try

```
SPSite msite = SPContext.Current.Site;
```

it does not work because the SPContext does not exist in the execute of the Job...

Any ideas?.

Thanks...!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SPFarm farm = SPFarm.Local;    
SPWebService webService = farm.Services.GetValue<SPWebService>("");
SPWebApplication webApplication = webService.WebApplications["Web Application name"];
foreach (SPSite site in webApplication.Sites)    
{
    // ...
}
```

For [Web Application-Scoped timer jobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798313.aspx) you can also use the `SPJobDefinition.Parent` property and cast it to the `SPWebApplication` type.